# How to see local class' member's value in Watch window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

In Visual C++ 2010, consider the following:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  struct MyClass
  {
    MyClass() : mMember(0)
    {}

  void Func()
  {
    int tmp = 0;
    tmp++;
  }

  private:
    int mMember;
  };

  MyClass inst;
  inst.Func();

    return 0;
}
```

Step inside Func() and go to Watches pane and watch member variable `mMember`. Instead of seeing its value, you'll see the error

> CXX0033: Error: error in OMF type information

Is it possible to get the debugger to display the member's value? If so, How?
I am aware this might be a bug, I have already reported it on Microsoft Connect, I am now looking for a workaround (that does not involve moving the definition outside function scope), and an explanation as to why this is occurring.
The bug report I submitted can be found here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760149/visual-c-2010-cant-view-local-class-members-in-debugger-cxx0033-error-error-in-omf-type-information

Edit: I am fully aware classes defined outside function scope work properly.

Edit2: A reference to an already submitted and acknowledged bug to Microsoft with this issue would go a long way towards becoming an accepted answer. I have searched for one already and found none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug, VS2008 has it too, but it was fixed in VS2012 so they'll surely quickly close your feedback article.

A workaround is going to be difficult, the debugger doesn't have type info for **this**.  Which also makes it give up the ghost on the watch expression.  Technically you can use Debug + Windows + Memory + Memory1 and type "this" in the Address expression.  The "somevarname" is the first member and the struct doesn't have a v-table so you'll have no trouble finding the value.  Clearly this doesn't scale very well.

Comment: thanks, your answer confirms my suspicions. Could you perhaps post a link to the bug report you are referring to? Thank you!
Also, unfortunately the real-life scenario does have a v-table, but your proposed solution is interesting nonetheless.

Comment: just tested this and it indeed has been fixed in VS2012

Answer (score 0):

Put your `MyClass` struct outside your main loop. Otherwise the debug info isn't generated properly for it. By moving it you can debug it's members normally. Without doing so, I don't believe there is any way to debug the members of that class. So to answer your question, no, there is not another way to debug local classes/structs as far as I know.

```
struct MyClass
{
   MyClass(/*int & aY*/) : 
//y(aY)
somevarname(0)
{}

void abc()
{
   int asdf = 0;
   asdf++;
}

private:
   //int & y;
   int somevarname;
} ;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


   MyClass implInst;
   implInst.abc();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the class is local to the function for a reason. I am aware classes defined outside function scope work properly.

Comment: Generally you don't NEED to make them local to the function. If you really need to debug it then move it outside the function. That's the only way I know of to allow you to debug it properly.

Comment: Thanks, the definition needs to be local to the function in this case. Defining references to member variables in abc()'s scope is one way to gain access to those members during debugging, that avoids moving the definition outside _tmain's scope. I'm just not interested in solutions involving changing code for debugging purposes.